# Trouble parsing JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, sockets

I have a socket in C sending this `char[]` (String) through a TCP socket:

```
{"time":0, "latitude":0.0000000, "longitude":0.0000000, "heading":0.000000, "roll":0.000, "pitch":0.000, "yaw":0.000}
```

It seems like it should be recognized as valid JSON in my Python client, but running:

```
parsed = json.loads(sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))
```

Generates the following error:

> ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 117 - line 1 column 1024 (char 117 - 1024

Maybe C is throwing in some extra bits that Python doesn't like.

Figuring this was the case, I trying calling `decode('ascii', 'ignore')` on the input String hoping this would strip these characters out, but nothing has worked so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what does it look like when you print it?

Comment: If I print `sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')` I get `{"time":0, "latitude":0.0000000, "longitude":0.0000000, "heading":0.000000, "roll":0.000, "pitch":0.000, "yaw":0.000}`, as I would expect.

Comment: @JamesTaylor: and what if you use `print repr(sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))`?

Comment: Oh. I get the JSON String I want trailed by a lot of `\x00\x00\x00` characters. These are probably the problem. Can I get rid of them?

Comment: Also, thanks! I had no idea the `repr()` function existed!

Comment: You might consider not sending those NULs in the first place, if the protocol you're using allows it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common to have to use:

```
.strip('\x00')
```

in Python to remove null terminators from C strings.